# Error while deciphering a string

Tags: python

Any inputs on what is wrong with line `phCmd = "ph %s return all".split(' ') % (qgroup)` ? I am trying to decipher the string `%s`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def main ():
    qgroups = ['tech.sw.list','tech.sw.amss']
    for qgroup in qgroups:
        print qgroup
        phCmd = "ph %s return all".split(' ') % (qgroup)
        phPipe = Popen(phCmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        (output, error) = phPipe.communicate()
        print output
        if phPipe.returncode != 0:
            print output
            raise IOError, "phcommand %s failed" % (phCmd)
        return output
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 9, in main
    phCmd = "ph %s return all".split(' ') % (qgroup)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"ph %s return all".split(' ') % (qgroup)
```

The [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) call returns a list, and `%` is undefined for the argument types list and tuple. I'm not sure what you mean to do here, but it looks like you want:

```
("ph %s return all" % (qgroup)).split(' ')
```

Comment: any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Comment: @user2639990 What are you trying to do, exactly? Can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 3):

The `.split(' ')` method call of a string returns a list. Try something like

```
phCmd = ("ph %s return all" % (qgroup)).split(' ')
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

When using "%" with strings, you have to place it right after the string.  This line of code

```
phCmd = "ph %s return all".split(' ') % (qgroup)
```

is actually telling Python to take the list returned by `"ph %s return all".split(' ')` and run an operation similar to:

```
>>> 2 % 2
0
>>>
```

on it using `(qgroup)`, which blows up.
To fix your problem, do this:

```
phCmd = ("ph %s return all" % qgroup).split(' ')
```